# Dynamics CRM identify primary contacts in contact entity

Tags: php, dynamics-crm

Trying to fetch all the primary contacts from CRM.

URL is: `/contacts`

Question is any field in contact entity to identify the contact is primary.

Example: `parentcustomerid = account id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this below one, which returns the primary contact from all accounts:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=_primarycontactid_value
```

Only to get Accounts with primary Contact contains data:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=_primarycontactid_value&$filter=_primarycontactid_value ne null
```